# Changing psql database name

Tags: postgresql

When I run psql, the user it defaults to is my username:

```
$ psql
psql (9.4.5)
Type "help" for help.

jeffrey.wan=#
```

How do I change it to something else?

```
psql -U jeffrey.wan desired_user
psql (9.4.5)
Type "help" for help.

desired_user=#
```

Comment: `psql -U god
psql: FATAL:  role "god" does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

Type `\?` to get the list of the available commands, and you will see that the one you are looking for is:

```
\c desired_user
```

By the way, the displayed name is the database you are connected to, not the user you are connected as.
You can specify another user by typing it as second parameter.

But you'd better look up for the [command line parameters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) when you connect the first time. For example, this will bring you where you want directly:

```
psql -d database -U user -h hostname
```

Comment: What do you mean "bring you where you want directly'

Comment: Well, it means you can specify the user and the database in the command line, instead of typing only "psql" and then trying to connect to another one.

Comment: Is there a permanent fix so I can just run psql in the future and have it point to the right database?

Comment: Either create an alias or set the environment variable "PGDATABASE" (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/libpq-envars.html). Otherwise, if you omit the "-d" option, "psql" tries to connect to a database whose name is your user. So either rename your database, connect with another user, or just use the parameter :)
If I answered your question, please accept it so that everyone knows this question is closed, thank you :)